# Understanding this Django search functionality

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have recently implemented a search functionality for Django Web application (it works just fine). However, I do not fully understand the workings of the code. Can you please explain what is going on, and specifically;:

- How does "get_queryset" & "get_contest_data" (views.py) work together?
- How does the search request (from template) know to go to "get_queryset"?
- What is return qs?

View:

```
from django.db.models import Q

class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    queryset = Product.objects.all()

def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    context["now"] = timezone.now()
    context["query"] = self.request.GET.get("q") #None
    return context

def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    qs = super(ProductListView, self).get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
    query = self.request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        qs = self.model.objects.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=query) |
            Q(description__icontains=query)
            )
        try:
            qs2 = self.model.objects.filter(
                Q(price=query)
            )
            qs = (qs | qs2).distinct()
        except:
            pass
    return qs
```

Template

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" method="GET" role="search"   action='{% url "products" %}'>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your `ProductListView` is a subclass of `ListView` is a subclass of `BaseListView` it has a `get` method. This `get` is called in case of a GET request and it calls `get_queryset` and `get_context_data`. See https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/list.py

Comment: And the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/intro/#using-class-based-views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template tells Django to send a GET request to the backend at the stated url with the param "q" (e.g. `www.example.com/products?q=search_term`)

Django matches the url and GET http method to the class ProductListView where q is passed as a param

`ListView` inherits from `BaseListView` where it sets the context from the method `self.get_context_data()` which you extended in your code. `BaseListView` inherits from `MultipleObjectMixin` which implements the `self.get_queryset()` method which you extended as well.

In short CBV (class base views) have a network of inheritance that define their different methods which can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUjyy.png). Many of the methods are hidden from you because of this inheritance chain so you either need to read the docs or better yet study the Django source code to figure out exactly whats happening.

As for return qs, qs is the queryset that you are returning in your extended `get_queryset()` method.

- Your taking the value q
- Filtering for any model that has the value of q in the title or description and storing it as a queryset in qs
- Filtering for any model that has a price of q and storing it as a queryset in qs2
- Combining querysets qs and qs2 and making sure each record is unique, then returning that queryset to be the queryset used by `ProductListView`

Comment: Thanks for telling me about CBV and quoting the exact methods. I can work backwards from here!